# Handling bad records in Snowpipe auto ingest

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake's snowpipe to do auto ingest of multiple files that have 1000 json records each. What I observe is that if any file has a bad record, say a record size > 16 MB limit that the variant column cannot hold, the pipe loads partial data from the file till the bad record entry and ignores rest of the records in the file. For instance, if I have a bad record at position 150, then only 149 records are loaded and remaining records out of 850 records are missed.
What I want is to just ignore the bad record and load all the other 999 records. Is there a configuration or something in the pipe that I can use? I'm using on_error = 'continue' currently in the pipe. Any help is much appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: Hi - are you using STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE ?

Comment: Wondering: What type of data are you ingesting, that it requires more than 16MB of compressed data per record?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa OP said it was JSON.

Comment: I believe the issue here is that `on_error='continue'` may not be appropriately handling a field overflow issue.  Since it can't load the whole record to determine where the record ends, it just errors completely out of the file.  This might be worth opening a support ticket with Snowflake to determine if there is a bug that needs to be handled.

Comment: @NickW Yes I'm using STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE to break the array of jsons to individual records.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Regular records are just a few KBs, but there are outliers once in a while with some blown up search data causing the records to grow beyond 16 MB which I want to handle by ignoring and continue loading rest of the records

Comment: @MikeWalton Yes that makes sense. I will open a support ticket with Snowflake. I could not find Snowflake official docs describing on_error parameter options. Would you know? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Sounds like a bug as @MikeWalton says. If you need a workaround while Snowflake investigate you could split your file into 1 record per file (so only the "oversize" files should be rejected) - how you would do that would depend on where your files are stored and what you are allowed to do with them i.e. process them within S3; download to your PC, process and upload; etc.

Comment: Yeah that's something I also thought about, but I'm worried that'll be too many files against what is allowed to do. Thanks for the suggestion however @NickW